# Cant resize a UIButton with CGRectMake

Tags: ios, swift, uianimation, cgrectmake

I have a button with a image on it, I am using **UIView.animateWithDuration** to assign a new size to the view as well as the image view.

The view scales up correctly, but there is no change to the image view

Code Snippet:

```
@IBAction func imageButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7) { 

        /*** Executes Properly ***/
        self.dialogView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth!, self.screenHeight!)

        /*** Does Not Execute ****/
        self.imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth!, 240)


        /*** Executes Properly ***/
        self.likeButton.hidden = true
        self.shareButton.hidden = true
        self.userButton.hidden = true
        self.headerView.hidden = true
        self.dialogView.layer.cornerRadius = 0

    }

}
```

Screenshot Before Button Press:
[image]

Screenshot After Button Press:
[image]

Screen Width and Screen Height Have been Defined in **viewDidLoad()**

```
screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
   screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
```

**EDIT 1:**
imageButton declaration

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageButton: UIButton!
```

**EDIT 2:**
I added a completion handler to the animate function:

```
    @IBAction func imageButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {


    print("Height Before:", self.imageButton.frame.height)
    print("Width Before:",self.imageButton.frame.width)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: { 

                    /*** Executes Properly ***/
                    self.dialogView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth!, self.screenHeight!)

                    /*** Does Not Execute ****/
                    self.imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenWidth!, 240)


                    /*** Executes Properly ***/
                    self.likeButton.hidden = true
                    self.shareButton.hidden = true
                    self.userButton.hidden = true
                    self.headerView.hidden = true
                    self.dialogView.layer.cornerRadius = 0



        }) { (true) in


            print("Height After:", self.imageButton.frame.height)
            print("Width After:",self.imageButton.frame.width)

    }

}
```

Console Screenshot: 
[image]

View Hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: is self.imageButton nil ?

Comment: No. Added in edit

Comment: Is autolayout enabled ?

Comment: @NDoc No luck. Check Edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check before setting imageButton size wether or not are you receiving you desired screenWidth.

The right place to get the `UIScreen` frame data is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as it is called after the subViews have been laid out in screen also it is called after every time your device changes orientation such as your width will be different when your user goes into landscape mode.This is called after `viewWillAppear:`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    screenWidth =  UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
  }
```

Then:-

If you are initialising and declaring your button **Programatically** :

```
print(self.screenWidth)

self.imageButton.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.screenWidth,240)
```

---

If you are using **AutoLayout** for the constraints, then :-

- Create an `@IBOutlet` of your button's width constraint in your class

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  ```
- Then set it accordingly.

  ```
   widthConstraint = self.screenWidth
  ```

> **Note:**
>   For conditions not using Auto Layout, when views are embedded within a view the **CGRectMake** function will only be executed for the parent view and not for the child view.

If needed to perform the operation with `CGRectMake`, Auto Layout needs to be disabled

Comment: Yes right. But I am using the same var **screenWidth** even for the dialog view and that scales properly

Comment: Yes, result remains the same

Comment: I changed the code to this: **self.imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.screenWidth!, 240)** but the imageButton still remains at (0,0)

Comment: Yes, using AutoLayout